# How do I invoke .getmethodinfo?

Tags: c#

I have recently started to read how a open source encryption program works.

The problem is, I'm stuck here on these 2 lines of code which I can't understand at all, I have looked at MSDN but it doesn't help me at all to understand what these 2 lines do.

```
MethodInfo run = Assembly.Load(InjRes).GetType("Resource.reflect").GetMethod("Run");
bool inj = (bool)run.Invoke(null, new object[] { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "", PayloadRes, false });
```

I'm also trying to figure out another way to accomplish the same thing, is there a way to invoke the .GetMethod?

Comment: You'll want to read a tutorial on [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly basic "reflection" in .NET.

Basically what happens here is:

- Loads a .NET assembly as indicated by `InjRes`
- Inside that assembly, get the type definition for `Resource.reflect` (which is probably a `class`)
- Inside the `Resource.reflect` type, get the `Run` method and save it to variable `run`
- Invoke (in other works, "execute") the `Run()` function on a `null` instance (which means `Run()` is probably a `static` method) with the parameters `(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "", PayloadRes, false)`

More simply, these lines would translate to "regular old C#" that looks like:

```
bool inj = Resource.reflect.Run(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "", PayloadRes, false);
```

but the original author probably couldn't have just written the simple 1 line above because either:

- The assembly wasn't referenced at build-time, so the compiler doesn't know about the `Resouce` namespace so would have thrown a compile error
- or the `Resouce.reflect` class or the `Run` method isn't `public` so couldn't have been called normally. Reflection can bypass this limitation.